# SQL Insert Statement not Working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, json, html, web-sql

I'm trying to get my WebSQL database to popluate using a JSON array (Object is called `myJSONObject`, array is called `costcodes`).

The function runs on click, the database successfully creates, but the data is not inserted into the database.  It doesn't even throw and error, it just doesn't do anything.

My initial thought was that the data isn't escaped properly, but I don't know exactly where/how to escape it.  So I'm stumped.

```
    localDB = null;

    function initDB()
    {
        if (localDB==null)
        {
            var shortName = 'Costcode';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'Costcode';
            var maxSize = 217802; // in bytes
            localDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
        }

    }
            function buildTable()
    {
       var sQuery = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Costcode ('+
                    'id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,' +
                    'cost_code_no VARCHAR NULL,' +
                    'row_unique_no VARCHAR NULL,' +
                    'cost_class_no VARCHAR NULL,' +
                    'Table_Version VARCHAR DEFAULT "1.0");';
        try
        {
            initDB();
            localDB.transaction(function(transaction)
            {
                transaction.executeSql(sQuery, []);
                console.log('sucess');
            });
        }
        catch (e)
        {
           alert("Error: Unable to create table 'x" + "' " + e + ".");
           return;
       }    
    }


 function exeSQLFast()
    {

                initDB();
                localDB.transaction(function(transaction)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x <myJSONObject.costcodes.length; x++)
                    {

                        var costcodeno = myJSONObject.costcodes[x].cost_code_no;
                        var rowuniqueid = myJSONObject.costcodes[x].row_unique_id;
                        var costclassno = myJSONObject.costcodes[x].cost_class_no;
                        console.log(costcodeno);
                        console.log(rowuniqueid); 
                        console.log(costclassno);
                    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Costcode (cost_code_no, row_unique_id, cost_class_no) VALUES (? , ? , ?)',
                     [costcodeno,
                     rowuniqueid,
                     costclassno]
                     , function(transaction, results)
                        {
                            console.log(costcodeno);
                            console.log('hooray');
                        }

                    )};
                    }
            )}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="buildTable();">
<input type="button" onClick="exeSQLFast();" value='button'>
</body>
</html>
```

The console log shows that the variables are all being properly defined, but it's not running the insert statement.  Any ideas?

Here's an example of `myJSONObject.costcodes[2]`

```
cost_class_no: "    3"
cost_code_no: "      1000"
row_unique_id: 335
```

That looks like a problem doesn't it...

Comment: This... looks scary as hell to me.  It's like a Sql Injection "Kick Me" sign.

Comment: I did not do anything to secure it yet, but that's not really my primary concern.  I am curious as to where I could add security, I am not particularly experienced in this kind of situation.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing of WebSQL, but as a general rule **never trust the client**.  Check, double-check, and sanitize your inputs before you get even close to anything resembling an SQL query.  The fact that you're building the query on the client side is an invitation for someone to get "creative" with the query.

Comment: I will agree with you 100% in all other SQL instances.  WebSQL, however, REQUIRES client side population as it is a browser based database.  Not to mention, I wouldn't exactly be that upset if someone injected this database as it is stored client side. The database that houses the actual information can't be touched from this particular script. You'd only be destroying the functionality of the webapp for yourself.

Comment: could you post the full code? im trying to reproduce the error.

Comment: I can't post the FULL (php included) code as it contains some relatively sensitive information, but I just posted the full javascript.  Even when I replace the values in the brackets with arbitrary strings, variables and integers ( x, 'dog', 1 ect.) it still doesn't work.  So you can try that instead of my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem was that I called the row_unique_no column row_unique_id in the insert statement. Now I feel stupid.
>
> But if anyone is curious how to populate a WebSQL database properly, this is how you do it. Just don't mistype the column names.