# backbone js store (large) remote collection locally

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, local-storage, requirejs, web-sql

I'm working on a backbone js html5 application for use on an iPad that has to work in on- and offline- mode.

The dataset I'm working with is relatively large:

- a remote collection of about 300 categories (each with about 3 properties)
- a remote collection of about 4000 items (each with about **150 properties** and a foreign key to a single category)

When in online mode, firstly the collection of categories should be fetched and stored locally. This information is quite stale so I only need to update this data every now and then.

When a category is selected the app should remotely fetch the items for that category (max 100). The user can also make a selection of items to store locally for use in offline mode. The amount of items that can be stored locally has to be limited for performance puprposes.

And now for my question ;-):

I would like to know the best way to go about fetching the remote collections and storing them in an offline database (probably webSQL?). Are there performance caveats that I should be on the lookout for?

If anyone is interested I can share come of the code I am working on. Currently the project is a combination of Backbone js, require js and JQuery Mobile.

Kind regards,

Jasper

Comment: Very similar to what I'm working on actually.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251419/sql-insert-statement-not-working-in-javascript is a question I asked about this a while back, may help you.  I've been looking at Backbone for a while just never got around to actually learning/implementing it.